# Make web socket connection between Ionic app to sails API with sails.io.js

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, sails.js, ionic-framework, sails.io.js

I'm having the same issue as described here [Connect from a client to a sails based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138152/connect-from-a-client-to-a-sails-based-server?lq=1) where socket continually retries to connect to sails.

I ran `sails new` from the command line and pulled out the latest sails.io.js file and added to my existing project I'm running sails version 0.11.0 which is a few versions ahead of the person in the question I referenced. Is there something else that could cause this?

Comment: Might want to file an issue in Github. The sails gitter is also a good place to seek support: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: yea, what is the path of the js file you're loading?

Comment: I've tried a couple of different ways. One using the bower install shown here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/ and loading either the sails.io.js found in the root of the directory or the one found in the dist directory. I've also ran sails new from the commend line and grabbed sails.io.js from the newly created sails app and adding it to my existing ionic app.

Comment: I've also been on gitter's driftyco/ionic room(balderdashy/sails wasn't offering much assistance) as you suggested and have been chatting with Rob Wormald about using angularSails there. Just tried installing that via Bower  but I am still getting the same errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you took the correct file? The file suggested in that post will not fit to your sails app version as it will fit to 0.10.5 version only. You may take your sails.io.js file from your sails app

> mySailsApp/assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js

also make sure that you specify the server's url that you want to communicate with as it automaticly refers to your localhost.

Comment: I did a `sails new myApp` to generate a new sails app to get the file from. Checked the version. It was 0.11.0 as was my original sails app. I grabbed the sails.io.js from the path you've listed and put it in my lib directory where the previously sails.io.js had been installed via bower as described [here] (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js?files=1) . When you mention specifying the server url I presume you mean in config/connection.js at my postgresql adapter in the sails app. Is there somewhere else it needs to be set?

Comment: add this to your client script: io.sails.url = 'http://your_server_address:1337/';. btw I was the one who opened that post so i'm very familiar with this error and it only accures when you're using the wrong sails.io.js file or not listed the server address. Also if this not solved your problem please copy your full error to here so I can examine it.

Comment: `GET https://localhost:1337/__getcookie net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSEDsails.io.js:212 jsonpsails.io.js:461 selfInvokingsails.io.js:483 SailsSocket._connectsails.io.js:1011 (anonymous function)`

Comment: So I had actually found that in the docs earlier today. Now I get this ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: What does that involve? Is that a setting in cors.js? or sockets.js?

Comment: Are you trying to communicate with your localhost sails or a live server?

Comment: I have an AWS RDS that my sails app is the API for. But I'm serving the sails app itself from localhost:1337. I came across these two things from a Google search on "__getcookie" https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/issues/14 https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sockets Do you think sails-hook-sockets is the solution I'm looking for?

Comment: I have no experience with this library but you can give it a shot. Another thing you can try is this:<script src="lib/sails.io.js/sails.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
    io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337/';
</script>

Comment: Adding `<script type="text/javascript"> io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false; io.sails.url = 'localhost:1337/';; </script>` worked. What is setting that to false doing?

Comment: In [this sails.io.js Github issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/issues/15) it's noted that setting this to false will disable socket support, which I need.

Comment: Glad you got this through @BradW . Unfortunately I dont remember what this script does xD as it was a long time ago. Just be grateful that it works.

Comment: I was just able to hit my database with io.socket.get() and log some data to the console. So I'm not sure what they were talking about in the github repo I referenced. Thanks for the solution @Matan

Comment: When setting `io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie` to `false` (and thus "*will disable socket support*") -- does this mean we're not using WebSockets (`ws://`)?